# Combine if conditions with contains function in fish shell

Tags: if-statement, fish

I can't seem to be able to combine multiple if conditions with `contains` function, see this example:

```
> function if_test
      if contains "h" $argv; or contains "-h" $argv
          functions if_test
          return
      end
  end
> if_test h
# ... works fine.
> if_test -h
# ... shows documentation of contains
```

This is weird because the following functions works as intended, so why is this different?

```
> if true; and false
     echo what
  else
    echo how
  end
how

> if true; or false
     echo what
  else
    echo how
  end
what
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-h` is interpreted as an option to `contains` - the short form of `--help`, so it prints `contains` help. Use `--` to signal the end of options:

```
if contains h -- $argv; or contains -- -h $argv
```

Note that the quotes here are merely a placebo - `"h"` is exactly equivalent to `h`. If there aren't any special characters (like spaces) quotes don't change anything.